# Wordpress / Ajax / jQuery / navigate to next and previous post inside a div

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, navigation

I'm trying to build a Wordpress theme using Ajax and jQuery. Whenever a link to a post is clicked on the front page the post loads inside div#single-post-container on the front page. I achieve this copying [Stan Kostadinov](http://stanhub.com/) [method](http://stanhub.com/load-wordpress-post-content-with-ajax-and-jquery/) :

The jQuery looks like this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    $(".post-link").click(function(){
            var post_link = $(this).attr("href");
            $("#single-post-container").removeClass("hidden");
            $("#single-post-container").html("");
            $("#single-post-container").load(post_link, function() {
                $(".close").click(function(){
                $("#single-post-container").addClass("hidden");
                });
            });
            $('body').scrollTop(0);
            return false;
});
});
```

Inside the post content being loaded I have the default Wordpress post navigation which gives me the following html :

```
    <div class="nav-links">
<div class="nav-previous"><a href="link-to-previous-post" rel="prev"><span>link</span></a></div>
<div class="nav-next"><a href="link-to-next-post" rel="next"><span>Link</span></a></div></div>
```

What I would like is whenever the next or previous post links are clicked to overwrite the default behavior, which opens the post in a new page and dynamically load/replace the content accordingly inside the same div#single-post-container on the front page.

I have tried adding this to my jQuery :

```
 $(".nav-previous a").click(function () {
var post_nav = $(this).attr("href");
       $( "#single-post-container" ).empty();
            $("#single-post-container").removeClass("hidden");
            $("#single-post-container").load(post_nav, function() {
                $(".close").click(function(){
                $("#single-post-container").addClass("hidden");
                });
            });
            $('body').scrollTop(0);
            return false;
});
```

With no luck. I have tried preventing the default behaviour by adding :

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Which also doesn't work. I'm a newbie to jQuery so please bear with me... I'm developing locally so I won't be able to show you the thing in action. I'll appreciate any help on this.

Please let me know if you need me to clarify.

Thanks.

Comment: preventDefault should be like this. did you add like this? $(".nav-previous a").click(function (e) {e.preventDefault(); also make  $(".nav-previous a").click(function () { this to " $(".nav-previous a").on("click",function () {"

Comment: Hi Farhan, Thanks for the interest in my question. I've just tried this, as you suggested : $(".nav-previous a").on("click",function (e) {
e.preventDefault(); It's still opening the post in a new page. It seems the preventDefault bit isn't doing anything.

Comment: also did you try $(".nav-previous a").on("click",function (e) {e.preventDefault();

Comment: Yes, that is what I have just tried.

Comment: any chance for demo?

Comment: Unfortunately not at this time, however I came up with a solution that works.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to make it work. Here is the jQuery if anyone is interested :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});

    $(".post-link").click(function(){
            var post_link = $(this).attr("href");
            $("#single-post-container").removeClass("hidden");
            $("#single-post-container").html("");
            $("#single-post-container").load(post_link, function() {
                $(".close").click(function(){
                $("#single-post-container").addClass("hidden");
                });
            });
            $('body').scrollTop(0);
            return false;
});

$('#single-post-container').on("click",'.nav-previous a',function () {
var post_nav = $(this).attr("href");
            $("#single-post-container").removeClass("hidden");
            $("#single-post-container").load(post_nav, function() {
                $(".close").click(function(){
                $("#single-post-container").addClass("hidden");
                });
            });
            $('body').scrollTop(0);
return false;
});


$('#single-post-container').on("click",'.nav-next a',function () {
var post_nav = $(this).attr("href");
            $("#single-post-container").removeClass("hidden");
            $("#single-post-container").load(post_nav, function() {
                $(".close").click(function(){
                $("#single-post-container").addClass("hidden");
                });
            });
            $('body').scrollTop(0);
return false;
});
});
```

Comment: What is the difference in code. Did you add nav_next and previous function or they were in code already?

Comment: The `.nav-next a` and `.nav-previous a` are loaded inside #single-post-container in the first part of the code. I therefore had to first indicate the parent container  ( #single-post-container ) of those elements for this to work. See here : `$('#single-post-container').on("click",'.nav-previous a',function () {`